# Add is-active class Bulma to router in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm working on the router in Vue js. I display the current link in Navbar by adding style for `router-link-active` and `exact` property for each `<router-link>`. It's work fine.

But now I'm trying to use class `is-active` (Bulma CSS) to do it. How can I do that ?.

Code

```
<a class="navbar-item is-active">
      <router-link to="/" exact>Home</router-link>
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-item">
        <router-link to="/about" exact>About</router-link>
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-item">
        <router-link to="/information" exact>Information</router-link>
    </a>
```

Any logical and solutions ? Please help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify the name of the active class in `vue-router` constructor by using the `linkActiveClass` option.

```
import Router from 'vue-router'

export default new Router({
 linkActiveClass: 'is-active',
 mode: 'history',
 routes: [ ... ]
})
```

This will add `is-active` class to the active router-link instead of `router-link-active`. Read the docs here: https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html#linkactiveclass

Comment: See also [linkExactActiveClass](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#linkexactactiveclass) option. You can also override these on specific `router-link` items by setting `exact-active-class=""` and `active-class=""` props.

Answer (score 0):

To add a class, simply put the `class` property on it:

```
<router-link class="is-active"></router-link>
```

Every component accepts that. It'll apply the class to the first element inside the component's template. In [`router-link`](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html)'s case, it's an `<a>` tag.

But keep in mind that `router-link` accepts a property `active-class` that you can use to put a css class to the currently active link, which sounds like what you're trying to do. So that's probably better, since Vue will detect which route you're currently at and put the class there for you.

Would look like this:

```
<router-link active-class="is-active"></router-link>
```

If you want to use this class on every active `router-link`, you can also set the [`linkActiveClass`](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html#linkactiveclass) option in the router's constructor so you don't have to set `active-class` in every link.